# Make box-counting code faster using Python

Tags: python, performance, audio, counting, box

The code below is one of the features on the audio file. Since I segmented one audio file to 4096 samples so I must call boxcounting function 4096 times to get the output for each segmented file. This code I wrote for one segmented file and called from the main python file. It takes around 10 seconds/segmented file if full audio is short and takes 30 seconds/segmented file if full audio is around 3-4 minutes. My problem is it takes a very long time to run one audio file.

1. get an array of from audio and separate them to 2 mono array (Left channel and Right channel)
2. normalize values and multiply array with 20 for scaling up
3. round numbers to one decimal place
4. pair them (L, R) by using zip()
5. remove the duplicate value
6. count coordinate pair in each small box
7. count boxes that have value (Final output)
   [This is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpu7X.jpg)

```py
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment
from collections import OrderedDict 

def difference(a, b):
    if (a > 0) and (b > 0):
        return (abs(a - b))
    elif (a > 0) and (b < 0):
        return abs(a + abs(b))
    elif (a < 0) and (b < 0):
        return (abs(a) - abs(b))

def boxcounting(left_channel, right_channel, scale):
    ratioX = difference(max(left_channel), min(left_channel))/scale
    ratioY = difference(max(right_channel), min(right_channel))/scale
    startX = min(left_channel)
    count_per_scale = []
    countbox = 0
    pair = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list(zip(left_channel, right_channel)))) 

    for x in range(scale):
        print('startX',startX)
        startY = min(right_channel)
        endX = startX + ratioX
        if x == (scale-1):
            endX = max(left_channel)
        print('endX',endX)
        for y in range(scale):
            print('-----------------------')
            print('startY',startY)
            endY = startY + ratioY
            if y == (scale-1):
                endY = max(right_channel)
            print('endY',endY)
            count = 0 # reset
            for l,r in pair:
                if (startX < l <= endX):
                    if (startY < r <= endY):
                        count+=1
                        print('0',l,r)
                        print('count',count)
                    elif (min(right_channel) == r and r == startY):
                        count+=1
                        print('1',l,r)
                        print('count',count)
                elif (min(left_channel) == l and l == startX):
                    if (startY < r <= endY):
                        count+=1
                        print('2',l,r)
                        print('count',count)
                    elif (min(right_channel) == r and r == startY):
                        count+=1
                        print('3',l,r)
                        print('count',count)
            count_per_scale.append(count)
            if count != 0:
                countbox += 1
            startY = endY
        startX = endX
        print('===============================')

    print(count_per_scale)
    countbox = 0
    for i in count_per_scale:
        if(i > 0):
            countbox += 1
    countbox = np.count_nonzero(count_per_scale)
    print('No. of box that has value =', countbox)
    return countbox

sound = AudioSegment.from_file('Alpharock - Pump This Party.mp3') 
split_sound = sound.split_to_mono()
left_channel = np.array(split_sound[0].get_array_of_samples())
right_channel = np.array(split_sound[1].get_array_of_samples())
scale = 10 #norm and scale up
scaleupL = np.round((left_channel/np.abs(left_channel).max())* scale,1) 
scaleupR = np.round((right_channel/np.abs(right_channel).max())* scale,1)
```

Can anyone help me to make it faster? Thank you very much.

Comment: your "final output" looks a lot like a histogram, if so then why not use [`hist2d` from matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d.html), if you really do want to do this counting, then [`histogram2d` from numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) might help you a lot

Comment: @SamMason Thank you very much for your suggestion. You help me a lot. I have already got the expected result using histogram2d.

Comment: If the args to `difference` are integers, then it can be simplified to just `return (abs(a - b))`.